# Annotation @InjectView not working after importing Butterknife in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations, butterknife

Just came across butterknife recently. I added the line in my gradle(module : app) file:
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

It synched without any errors. I'm able to import 'butterknife.Butterknife' to my class file where the imports usualyy go. But cant import butterknife.InjectView doesn't seem to be there?  Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show code plz

Comment: did you bind the activity ?

Comment: There is no code...I can't import butterknife.InjectView to use the annotation @InjectView

Comment: Just look at this http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 5):

The Butterknife 7.0.0 release included the breaking change of renaming of the annotation verbs. This is highlighted in the changelog and reflected in the website.

```
Version 7.0.0 *(2015-06-27)*
----------------------------

 * `@Bind` replaces `@InjectView` and `@InjectViews`.
 * `ButterKnife.bind` and `ButterKnife.unbind` replaces `ButterKnife.inject` 
    and `ButterKnife.reset`, respectively.
...
```

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md

A very good, and up-to-date, introduction to the usage is at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Here is the simplest usage:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @Bind(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @Bind(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
  @Bind(R.id.footer) TextView footer;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`@InjectView` is no more available and is replaced by `@BindView`. We will have to import `Butterknife` dependencies to use the annotations. More on butter knife here :- http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

`@BindView` annotation could be implemented as :-

```
@BindView(R.id.button_id)
```

Note that you will need to call `ButterKnife.bind(this);` from `onCreate()` method of the main activity to enable Butterknife annotations. An example on this implementation could be something like :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatibilityActivity{
    @BindView(R.id.editText_main_firstName)
    EditText firstName;
    @BindView(R.id.editText_main_lastName)
    EditText lastName;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Needs to be called to enable Butterknife annotations
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }
}
```

If you are using `Butterknife` in a fragment then use `Butterknife.bind(this,view)` the view being the fragment view i.e. :-

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_other_product_category, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `@InjectView` was replaced by `@Bind`.

Furhtermore you have to call `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in your `onCreate()`.

see: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/